# JS: Add ellipsis if string length exceeded 50 characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

Is it possible to use ternary operator to add '...' if string exceeds 50 characters?

I tried it like this but it doesn't work.

```
{post.title.substring(0, 50) + post.title.length > 50
                    ? '...'
                    : ''}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You are not saying how it doesn't work but my guess is that you need parenthesis: `... + (post.title.length > 50 ? ... : ...)`.

Comment: But you might consider using CSS for this, rather than JavaScript. See [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). You'll probably need `white-space: nowrap` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional operator¹ is fairly greedy. To have it apply only to the part of your expression after the `+`, you need parentheses (the grouping operator):

```
{post.title.substring(0, 50) + (post.title.length > 50
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
                    ? '...'
                    : '')
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
}
```

But you might consider using CSS for this, rather than JavaScript. See [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). You'll probably need `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden;` as well:

```css
.limit {
    max-width: 20em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>With limit:</div>
<div class="limit">Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country</div>
<div>Without limit:</div>
<div>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country</div>
```

---

¹ `? :` is **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands), and for the moment it's JavaScript's only ternary operator, but there could be others in the future. Its name is the *conditional* operator.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
var shortTitle = post.title.length > 50 ? post.title.substring(0,50) + "..." : post.title;
```

Comment: Spelling mistake. titie->title :p